# For plone.api, how do I set the current portal if it is not /Plone?

Tags: plone

`plone.api.portal.get()` gets the current portal out of thin air. If it shouldn't be `/Plone`, how do I set the current portal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zope.component.hooks.setSite(...)`

Comment: You should only need to do this in something like a Zope "run" script. The site is normally set via traversal. Traversal, the process of walking through the ZODB object graph to reach an object while handling a request, is the questioner's "thin air."

Comment: Thanks, I do mainly use plone.api in maintenance scripts that are not part of a web request.